# git merge changes from head to local

Tags: git

I am pretty new to got and need some help.  I apologize if my question is trivial or stupid.

Anyway, I synced from a remote branch, made some changes, checked some in, but others I never staged (because I don't want them checked in).

Now I need to sync to that remote repository, but not lose the local untracked changes.  Ideally, it would be great if git would allow my to review changes if there are any conflicts.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Based on your comment to Learath2's answer, you may want to take a look at [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes), specifically part titled *Keyword Expansion*.  Basically it lets you apply changes to to a file (like your config file) on checkout and strip them back out on commit.

Comment: Mind either choosing a correct answer or if you solved it yourself post the answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [stash](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) command to back up changes in untracked files, something like

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

The documentation link above provides an example called *Pulling into a dirty tree*, which is probably similar (or identical) to your situation.  If there are merge conflicts when you try to apply stashed changes git will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Thats why you should always work with branches. Anyways you can `git stash save` your work and then `git commit` and `git push`. After that you can `git stash apply` to get your other changes back.

Comment: I think you're missing some punctuation.

Comment: true writing from ipad bear with it ill fix it

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It looks like stash should help me out, but you say that I should work with branches.  Let me explain my situation and then get some recommendations on how best to do that.  The reason that I have local files changed sans staging is that I am using a different dev enviroment from everyone else on my team and need a few minor tweaks to some of the build artifacts in order to build locally, but those changes should never be checked in.  Any advice how to manage that with branches?

Comment: Well your workspace changes shouldn't be tracked by git anyways. So switching branches wouldn't change them